# What factors limit a shape and size of an organ

Tags: human-anatomy

We all know that anatomy deals with structure of human system. I am interested in knowing the factors that determine the shape and size of each organs in the body. For example, we know that kidneys are bean shaped, stomach is a C- shaped organ.

During the developmental stage, like mitosis, and other cellular pathways, what factors sets a boundary for cell division, so that an organ takes its respective size and shape.

Comment: Externally applied forces, contact signaling and intracellular checkpoint systems work in concert and underly tissue development, but as far as I know it's very poorly understood! [Interesting, related article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3992650/)

Comment: To be precise, size and shape of an organ involves mechanobiology. Thanks Kendall for the supportive article.

Comment: Every organ is going to be way to broad, each organ has its own pathways.